# Nuxt 3 project running in a subdirectory trying to find assets in root instead of subdirectory

Tags: subdirectory, nuxt3, base-url

I could run Nuxt 3 in a subdirectory after setting the app.baseURL in nuxt.config.ts as mentioned in the official documentation.
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#baseurl

It works fine on development, but on production after building, the assets included in app.head.link and app.head.script are not found as its source considering the root path instead of the subdirectory!

I tried to set app.cdnURL as mentioned in the official docs, but I hasn't any effect.
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#cdnurl

nuxt.config.ts file

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
ssr: false,
   app: {
      baseURL: '/admin',
      cdnURL: '/admin',
      head: {
        link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/imgs/logo.png' },],
        script: [{ type: 'text/javascript', src: "/js/main.js", tagPosition: "bodyClose" },]
      }
})
```

appreciating you suggestions.
Thank you.